# Handle error message when displaying PDF in an IFrame

Tags: html, http, pdf, iframe

I'm trying to display PDF in the browser when clicked on it. I'm creating an Iframe and setting PDF url as src. This works fine when the URL returns 200 and I can display that PDF in the IFrame.

Problem is, when a GET request to this PDF URL fails(returns anything other than 200), IFrame displays the response.

So the iframe will show this text, which is response of http get on pdf url.

```
{"message":"Pdf is unavailable"}
```

How do I handle error case and display a custom message on iframe?

Answer (score 0):

One alternative method to load pdf in iframe is to use new PDFObject.
  You may setup a PDFLoader within , and then use Javascript snippet to embed the pdf.
var mypdf = new PDFObject({
  url: "http://example.com/def.pdf",
  id: "pdfRendered",
  pdfOpenParams: {
    view: "FitH"
  }
}).embed("PDFLoader");